# What is a sufficient sample size for a logisitic multilevel (three-level) analysis?

Tags: logistic, repeated-measures, sample-size, multilevel-analysis, generalized-estimating-equations

I have an exploratory research question for which I use a repeated measure design with 3 levels:

- level 1 = 3 measurement occasions per day
- level 2 = day
- level 3 = participan

To keep the effort for the participants low, the unit size for level 1 and 2 are fixed (N1 = 3 measurement occasions a day, and N2 = 7 days per participant). I can only determine the number of units for level 3 (aka. participants).

In my analysis, I will focus on 6 predictors at level 1 and their influence on my dependent variable also measured at level 1, hence I am looking for a sufficient sample size to gain information about those regression coefficients. But how do I determine it?

I had a look at different sample size calculators, but many address two-level designs only (e.g. PinT Power in Two-level designs). I have tried using MLPowSim, but there is not a lot of data on my research topic, so I had trouble identifying estimates for the coefficients, which are required by the programm as input. (Also, there was an error in the R-code, so i wasn't able to run it).  Furthermore I combed through articles about sample size for multilevel models, but again many papers only include 2-level models (e.g. Maas, C. J., & Hox, J. J. (2005). Sufficient sample sizes for multilevel modeling. Methodology, 1(3), 86-92.)

To my understanding so far, what most papers seem to do, is to run simulations on existing data and then base their recommentations on these simulations (e.g. Kerkhoff & Nussbeck 2019).
Heo & Leon (2008) for example indicate that fewer than 10 units at level 1 and level 2 require more than 30 units at level 3. (But their calculations have been made for a RCT).
Another paper states that in order to estimate the fixed effects slope, unit sizes of 3/10/100 can result in unbiased parameter estimates. The problem with this recommentation is that the model used for the simulations had 3 predictors (one on each level) and therefore does not match my proposed model (with 6 predictors on level 1).

I also read that it is primarily important to have a sufficiently large sample size at my level of interest, which would be the first level. Does that mean that I can simply use e.g. the GPower calculator for logistic regression and then calculate back how many participants I need at level 3? (Let's say the gpower calculator advised me to have 900 units at level 1 in total, which (divided by 3 (level 1) and divided by 7 (level 2)) results in around 42 participants?

I am greatful for some input.